# Typescript how to pass props in parent component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I am practicing typescript. I have error "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'" for setAuthenticated(valueFromChild) line and "...is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'." for all places(,) where I pass props into child components here. How do I fix the errors?

```
import { FunctionComponent, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './Components/navbar.component';
import './App.css';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import theme from './Theme/theme';
import Login from './Components/login.component';
import Register from './Components/register.component';

const App: FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const handleAuth = (valueFromChild: boolean): boolean =>
    setIsAuthenticated(valueFromChild);
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Navbar isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
        <Switch>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/login"
            render={(props) => <Login {...props} handleAuth={handleAuth} />}
          />
          <Route
            exact
            path="/register"
            render={(props) => <Register {...props} handleAuth={handleAuth} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState<boolean>(false);
const handleAuth = (valueFromChild: boolean): boolean =>
    setIsAuthenticated(valueFromChild);
```

You are saying that `handleAuth` must return `boolean`.  But calling `setIsAuthenticated` returns `void`.  You probably just want to make `handleAuth` return `void`.  Or you can leave off the return type and let Typescript infer it correctly.

```
const handleAuth = (valueFromChild: boolean): void =>
    setIsAuthenticated(valueFromChild);
```

> "...is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'." for all places(,) where I pass props into child components here.

It seems like your components `Login` and `Register` don't accept any props.  Do they accept a `handleAuth` prop?

They should be defined similar to this:

```
export interface AuthProps {
  handleAuth: (value: boolean) => void;
}

export const Login: React.FunctionComponent<AuthProps> = ({handleAuth}) => { ...

export const Register: React.FunctionComponent<AuthProps> = ({handleAuth}) => { ...
```

The props that you are passing from `(props) =>` are the `RouteComponentProps` which includes `match`, `location`, etc.   You could include these in the props type for your `Login` and `Register` components.  But if you don't need to use these props in the component then you can just not pass them.

```
render={() => <Login handleAuth={handleAuth} />}
```